# how to get methods code from a file in php without removing back to line and tabs

Tags: php, reflection

i m trying to make a function that can read a file and return the name of methods and their correspond code " similar to reflection but reflections remove return to line and tabs and i wanna keep them to show them out in the editor .
i tried this but it removes the spaces and back to line

```
function get_sourcecode($classname, $methodename)
{

    $func = new ReflectionMethod($classname, $methodename);
    $filename = $func->getFileName();
    $start_line = $func->getStartLine() - 1; // it's actually - 1, otherwise you wont get the function() block
    $end_line = $func->getEndLine();
    $length = $end_line - $start_line;

    $source = file($filename);
    $body = implode("", array_slice($source, $start_line, $length));

    return $body;
}
```

Comment: What does this mean _but reflections remove return to line and tabs_???

Comment: sorry i mean Spaces and line breaks

Comment: Reflection is probably the wrong tool for this job. Have a look at tokenizers.